# How to source the initial requirements for an app?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, users, user-centered-design

I have an app idea but do not know  how to do an initial requirements documentation. Do I do a survey based on what features I think would be good? Do I do a competitive analysis?

I have no budget to recruit users but could rely on some guerrilla methods like approaching people at a local cafe?

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you're thinking the wrong way 'round. Requirements first is  [waterfall design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model#Criticism). And it's a surefire way to make something on budget and on time that everyone will hate and noone will use.

Of course, even if you see your first implementation as nothing more than a starting point, you need something to get started. But a list of requirements locks down all of your design before anyone has had a chance to think about it and a feature by name alone means nothing. You have to place things in context.

My advice would be to start with a simple model of what your users are going to be (some personas, user roles, maybe some axes to place you users on) and start writing **user stories**. Just two or three sentences describing who your user is, and what they want to accomplish. Make no assumptions about what you're going to build or what features will be included. Just **who is the user, what does she want?**

From the user stories, you'll get a picture of what a minimal application might look like. I'd follow these principles:

- Don't include a feature unless it covers two or more different user stories. Features are easy to add, but difficult to remove.
- Include the client in the design. If you drop a design on someone's desk after four weeks of development they'll never go along with it. All stakeholders need to follow the process and see the reasoning behind it. That means the client, the users and the developers.
- Don't do dead documents. Don't make long technical documents that noone is going to read. Write simple user stories and illustrate how you're going to implement them with low-fi prototypes like wireframes.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is a paper project, so there is no client right now. I just need a grounding base to work from. Do you suggest the same methodology?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a paper project? Like a project for a university course?

Comment: FWIW, I've never been part of a waterfall project that was also on budget. ;)

Comment: "Requirements first is waterfall and thus sure to result in something everyone will hate and no one will use?" Scuse me? Since when is it stupid to sit down and think about what some app should do/what problem it should solve? And since when does that imply waterfall? I am pretty sure that stories in agile are pretty much requirements?

Comment: Yes, Peter. A paper project is what I mean that it will not be executed and developed for market release.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I think there is a big difference between writing a requirements document and writing user stories. I guess you could interpret "requirements" as anything that helps to define the general shape of an app, but in practice, it always means a list of features. There's a big difference between saying "we should have a wysiwig editor" and saying "an editor wants to fit a press release to the house style". A user story is a way of talking about what the app should do without locking down requirements.

Comment: @Inlin in that case there's probably some thought behind your assignment. Maybe your professor (or whatever) wants you to do waterfall-style requirements analysis. There are plenty of people who still believe in it, especially in universities. In that case, you should do as you're told to get the credit. And it may make for great project management. But I don't think it makes for good UX.

Comment: Well Peter, I am not in an academic setting. But I am trying to put this project together as part of a professional portfolio. I want it to be as real as possible, but of course without the budget and resources of one.Thanks.

Comment: But why do you have the knee jerk reaction that "requirements" without any further elaboration equates to a list of features? And a list of features can very well incorporate the "why" for the feature. User stories have been evangelized as the "true" way of getting to an app users want to use. They are not the only way and in and of themselves don't necessarily achieve it. Oh heck, I am babbling. The point is: don't knee jerk when hearing a term used. Ask what someone means before jumping to conclusions (learned that the hard way and relearning it about every 1-2 years).

Comment: @MarjanVenema Maybe it is a bit kneejerk of me, but requirements is a laden term. It does kind of imply locking things down, to me. I mean, if it's required, then we have to make it once it's in the requirements. And if we have to make it, it needs to be specified exactly, otherwise you can't require it of us. Anyway, you're absolutely right that I'm leaping to conclusions in assuming that's what's going on here. Please consider this as one possible answer among many (even if nobody else is answering).

Comment: @Inlin Maybe you should create a new question where you give that as context. I'd say the document should reflect the kind of work you'd like to do (and expect to be able to do). If you want to work in Agile environments, I'd focus on doing lightweight user studies (informal, hallway testing, etc.) and creating a quick, living prototype rather than a dead document. If you want to work in more formal projects, you may want to focus on other, more strict methodologies, but most UX people tend to favor the Agile side of things.

Comment: Ah, it's the R-word! I have a similar knee jerk to "must". Especially in our common native language where "I/You must B" it is an over-used and abused short-cut for "because I want A, I/you need to do B". No worries mate, I already liked your answer, as well as others I have seen by you.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Thanks :) It's a lot like the way people use "moeten", you're right. Locking things down, instead of expressing desires. Very frustrating.